# Changing content URL of an image using @media property

Tags: html, css, image, user-interface, responsive-design

I'm trying to develop a **responsive** webpage. I'm supposed to show two different images in the desktop view and the mobile view. I tried to change the image **using the @media property of CSS**, like this.

```
 #login-top-shadow{
         max-width: 100%;
         @media only all and (max-width: 700px) {
         content:url("img/login_top_shadow_mobile.png");
   }
}
```

The image which is supposed to be shown in the desktop view is given for the **src** attribute of my image.

**While** **reducing the size of the page, the image does not change.** I**t changes in the CSS properties in the console but not in the html**.

Is this the correct approach to place images while placing images in responsive web- design?
Attaching the screen shot of my console.[image]

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle.

Comment: FYI: changing an image by CSS `content` does not work in all browsers. You might want to consider the [`picture`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) element.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you that you create a `div` and then set it's `background-image` to something.

https://jsfiddle.net/6hj41pft/

```
    <div></div>

    div {
    background-image: url('http://images.clipartpanda.com/clipart-sun-decorative_sun_clip_art_23259.jpg');
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    background-size: cover;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    div {
        background-image: url('https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/85/209708058_b5a5fb07a6_z.jpg?zz=1');
    }
}
```

Comment: @alirezasafian that should be the answer

Comment: @Mi-Creativity I can not post it until Rogen George post his all css and html. It might not be answer of Rogen George's question.

Comment: yup you are right i just had another look at the screenshot and he is already using the same technique you just posted in jsfiddle